# Same (organization) IP address with multiple users

Tags: discussion, voting, sock-puppets, voting-fraud

<sup>The title was tricky to word. Suggestions welcome.</sup>

I work for a digital agency (which I'm sure isn't at all uncommon) and as I was recently hired on, I've been encouraging a few coworkers to contribute more to and interact with Stack Overflow as part of our routine workflow.

However, one concern and one question come to mind:

- Does Stack Overflow care that multiple accounts are coming from the same WAN IP address? Our computers are on the same intranet and thus all outbound connections to Stack Overflow will be seen from the same IP. I'm sure (at least I'd hope) SO is smart about this and judges users on their behavior, not their technical means of access.
- If we're having a problem on our team that affects more than one of us, is it unethical/viewed poorly to have a teammate ask a question and for me or another teammate to upvote it? It's not like we have 15 people on our team all upvoting - it'd be one or two tops. Is this considered puppeting/gaming votes since we are all facing the same issue and are unable to resolve it?

I would assume *no* and *yes* could be answered respectively (which is why we're abstaining from upvoting) but I'm interested in seeing how this is handled by moderators/the anti-fraud mechanism.

Comment: Regarding first question: I think SO uses a cookie, not technical access. For example, it is also allowed to be logged in simultaneously on three devices. When I change my mobile from WiFi to 3G mobile access, I do not need to log in again.

Comment: @Sjips The fact that you can login from multiple locations doesn't mean that SE doesn't keep track of and pay attention to your IP address, because they do, and it is one tool, among many, that is used to determine if a user is abusing the site through the use of multiple accounts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Does StackOverflow care that multiple accounts are coming from the same WAN IP address?

Not unless they start acting like a sock puppet ring - which is only answering each other's questions, only voting on each other's posts etc. If you each use the site normally then there's nothing that you'll do that will attract the attention of the moderators.

> If we're having a problem on our team that affects more than one of us, is it unethical/viewed poorly to have a teammate ask a question and for me or another teammate to upvote it?

Yes, this is the very behaviour that will attract the attention of the moderators and could end up with votes invalidated, accounts suspended or even deleted.

Comment: I don't agree entirely. If you have a big team who work on a problem and you all use SO there could be occasions where a "teammate" answers your question so they leave answer on SO. I don't see a problem with that but consistent up-votes between "teammates" would start to cross a line.

Comment: This is in my humble opinion a bad move. Why? Because the same happend to my friend. We are in the same faculty and living in the same students accomodation, he is my room mate. I have the wifi we deployed for our lappies. Yet, all of a sudden, his account yesterday was removed and all his researches and information in all the time with it. We don't know now what to do, emailing customer service takea ages for a reply.

Comment: believe it or not, I downvoted a teammate because his question on SO was terrible (I even flagged a "thank you" answer from him for deletion). After he improved it a great deal, I upvoted it. I NEVER ask my teammates to upvote me, and I think they don't do it until they are _really_ interested in the question/answer. and it's best left this way.